# Number of integral solutions to the equation $x^{2}+y^{2}=n$ and Dirichlet Character

Tags: number-theory

Define a function $\chi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{0,1,−1\}$ as follows: $χ(d)=\begin{cases} 1 & d \equiv 1\ \text{mod} \ 4 \\ -1 & d \equiv 3\ \text{mod} \ 4 \\ 0 & \text{for every even} \ d \end{cases}$

Prove that the number of integral solutions to the equation $x^2 + y^2 = n, (n ≥ 0)$, with $x > 0,y ≥ 0$, is equal to
$$\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)$$
where the summation runs over all positive divisors of n.

Comment: Done: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an Euclidean domain.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Asking for the proof of some statement (well-known, in this case, see *Cox, primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*) without providing further context is considered to be rude. MSE is not a homework-solving service for free, please improve your question by following the guidelines above.